# ASP.NET Site crashing on Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an ASP.NET application which is crashing, and I have not been able to repro the issue locally. When I open up the crash dump file using DebugDiag I am seeing many instances of the below exception.

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Guid'. Please use a nullable
>   type.    System.Data.DataRowExtensions+UnboxT`1[[System.Guid,
>   mscorlib]].ValueField(System.Object)
>   System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[[System.Guid,
>   mscorlib]](System.Data.DataRow, System.String)
>   Extension.FieldSub[[System.Guid, mscorlib]](System.Data.DataRow,
>   System.String)

Below is the application code from the stack trace. I am wondering if it is possible that a LINQ background thread is causing the crash. If it is a LINQ background thread how does the DB and web app handle this issue? It appears that it will keep going for some time, but that as these exceptions pile up eventually it crashes.

```
public static T FieldSub<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
     object result = null;
     try
     {
         result = row.Field<T>(columnName);
     }
     catch {}

     if (result == null)
     {
         result = default(T);
     }
     return (T)result;
}
```

Comment: `System.Guid` is a struct. It is not nullable. `System.Guid?` would be nullable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to validate if the data is null, try this:

```
result = row.IsNull(columnName) ? default(T) : row.Field<T>(columnName);
```

Comment: Doesn't this now make the `result` local variable unnecessary, you might as well just turn this line into a return statement. `return row.IsNull(columnName)  ? default(T) : row.Field<T>(columnName)`;

Comment: Thanks is the check I have for result == null not sufficient then in this case? I have not seen any issue with this until we started using GUID types, and I can't repro the issue in the debugger unless I hard code the result to DBNULL.Value

Comment: That's because null != DB.Null, Guid could be Guid.Empty but null